# What are practical embedded system uses for each type of register configuration?

Tags: embedded, shift-register, register

I'm interested in giving my students information about the following four types of registers in the context of microcontrollers and embedded system design. I am listing the uses (to my knowledge) of each type of register. Are there other practical uses for these types of registers? In particular, when/where would SISO registers be used in embedded system applications?

**Parallel In / Parallel Out (PIPO)**

- Accumulators
- General purpose and I/O registers (etc.)

**Serial In / Parallel Out (SIPO)**

- Input serial data to store in PIPO registers/memory

**Parallel In / Serial Out (PISO)**

- Load data from PIPO registers/memory, and output as a serial stream

**Serial In / Serial Out (SISO)**

- ??

Comment: This question is not a fit here.  Stack exchange sites are for singular, specific questions that have specific answers.  "What are..." type questions *seeking an enumeration of possibilities* do not fit this model and mission.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of to have a SISO register would be to act as a delay in a shift register path or a scan chain. But in that case, it's not really a register, it's just some extra flops in the middle of the chain.

I have seen a hybrid register that could do all four operations: serial in, serial out, parallel in, *and* parallel out. It was used to allow the CPU to read and write values to a chain of flops.